# Loading one raster into QGIS from a table of rasters in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, postgresql

I have a question about loading raster layers into QGIS from PostGIS, it's a an extension from the question asked [here] : [Loading PostGIS raster layer into QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76297/loading-postgis-raster-layer-into-qgis?newreg=b17020a65dcb40b093c2526410098db3)
'DB Manager', 'add to canvas' works fine, when my PostGIS table contains only 1 raster.

However, I have set up a table where each row has it's own raster, and I am trying to load just the raster that results from a query. So for example, I run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM raster_table WHERE rid = 8;
```

This returns the row I am after - which contains a value in the rid column and a value in the raster column relating to the raster, however when I try to load the raster by checking "Load as new layer" and completing the dialog box, I can only get a table to load containing just the rid. I can't get a raster to load from the query.

Could anyone explain if it is possible to do it this way, or does a raster need to be saved in PostGIS individually?

Comment: This is basically the same questions as [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234945/loading-selected-records-in-postgis-raster-table-into-qgis-using-db-manager?rq=1). My impression is that raster queries are not yet implemented. As a workaround I have run the query in PostGIS to create a temporary raster table with one row and then displayed this one. Maybe this can also be done with views.