# Using raster2pgsql to display data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, postgis-raster

I am quite new to this process (using raster data in PostGIS) and tried to find some tips/solutions on other threads but I didn't manage to get things working.

I ingested some Landsat data into my database using:

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -s 28356 LS7_20150425_B50.tif public.LS7_20150425_B50 | psql –d postgres –U postgres
```

And everything is working fine : I see my new table LS7_20150425_B50 with two columns (rid and rast) and I am able to compute some stats on my raster using ST_SummaryStats().

However, I'd like to display my raster in QGIS (2.12.0 Lyon) using the DB Manager. However, when I am adding the table to the canvas I am getting an error message:

```
PG: dbname=postgres host=localhost user=postgres port=9999 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=ls7_etm_nbar_p54_ganbar01-002_089_078_20150425_b40 is not a valid layer.
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is layer name not limited in length? Your table name is 50 characters long... Maybe try with a shorter name.

Comment: @wiltomap I tried to rename my table with a shorter name "b10" and I am still getting the same error message : PG: dbname=postgres host=localhost user=postgres port=9999 mode=2 schema=public column=rast table=b10 is not a valid layer and cannot be loaded.

Comment: @wiltomap In fact after restarting QGIS, it is now working fine. I don't know if it is related to the name length or not. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Glad it worked! Welcome on GIS StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem  has not been solved by directly renaming the table names.

However, the problem has been solved after :

- performing again the ingestion of rasters with shorter names for the tables in raster2pgsql commands
- changing the language default to English on QGIS
- restarting QGIS

I guess that the first point has been the real solution to solve my issue but just in case I prefer to mention the two other points.

Maybe this can also be related to [this topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/61095/loading-raster-from-postgis-db-into-qgis-succeeded-yesterday-fails-now).